# Find key of list of lists by value

Tags: python, list

im new to python and im failing to achieve this.

I have two lists of lists:

```
list1 = [['user1', 'id1'], ['user2', 'id2'], ['user3', 'id3']...]
list2 = [['id1', 'group1'], ['id1', 'group2'], ['id2', 'group1'], ['id2', 'group4']...]
```

And what i need is a single list like this:

```
[['user1','id1','group1'],['user1','id1','group2'],['user2','id2','group1']]
```

I suppose I could iterate all the lists and compare values but i think there must be some built-in function that allows me to saerch a value in a list of lists and return the key or something like that. But i cant find anything for multidimensional lists.

Note that the idN value in the first list not necessarily exists in the second one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is it possible to use dictionaries instead of lists ?

Comment: one lists come from a rest request and the other from an ldap search, im creating them appending each sub list to the main one. I think i could make a dictionary instead but i dont know how.

Comment: Lists don't have "keys" so there is no such built-in function. You should be using a `dict` if you want to associate key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing in python. There are methods for multidimensional arrays in `numpy`, but they are not really suitable for text.

Your second list functions as a dictionary, so make one

```
dict2 = {key:value for key, value in list2}
```

and then

```
new_list = [[a, b, dict2[b]] for a, b in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use lists of lists, you can use a comprehension to achieve this.

```
list1 = [['user1', 'id1'], ['user2', 'id2']]
list2 = [['id1', 'group1'], ['id1', 'group2'], ['id2', 'group1'], ['id2', 'group4']]

listOut = [[x[0],x[1],y[1]] for x in list1 for y in list2 if x[1] == y[0]]

output => [['user1', 'id1', 'group1'], ['user1', 'id1', 'group2'], ['user2', 'id2', 'group1'], ['user2', 'id2', 'group4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
list1 = [['user1', 'id1'], ['user2', 'id2'], ['user3', 'id3']]
list2 = [['id1', 'group1'], ['id1', 'group2'], ['id2', 'group1'], ['id2', 'group4']]

final_list=[]
for sublist in list1:
    for item in sublist:
        for sublist1 in list2:
            for item1 in sublist1:
                if item==item1:


                    final_list.append(("".join(sublist[:1]),item1,"".join(sublist1[1:])))

print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[('user1', 'id1', 'group1'), ('user1', 'id1', 'group2'), ('user2', 'id2', 'group1'), ('user2', 'id2', 'group4')]
```